# How to do integral $\int_0^T \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t(T-t)}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2t}}dt$ and $\int_0^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{t(T-t)}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2t}}dt$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I met these two integrals but don't know how to do them:

$$I_1 = \int_0^T \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t(T-t)}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2t}}\text{d}t$$

$$I_2 = \int_0^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{t(T-t)}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2t}}\text{d}t$$

where $b>0$, $T>0$.

Please kindly help?

---

Thanks to hits from Fabien, for the first one, let $t=\frac{T}{u^2+1}$:

$$I_1 = \int_0^T \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t(T-t)}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2t}}\text{d}t = \frac{2}{T}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2T}} \int_0^{+\infty}  e^{-\frac{b^2}{2T}u^2} \text{d}u  = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{b\sqrt{T}} e^{-\frac{b^2}{2T}} $$

seems this tally with Mhenni Benghorbal's result.

For the second one, let $t=\frac{T}{u^2+1}$, $a^2=\frac{b^2}{2T}$:

$$I_2  =2 e^{-\frac{b^2}{2T}} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+u^2}  e^{-\frac{b^2}{2T}u^2} \text{d}u  =2 e^{-a^2}  \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+u^2}  e^{-a^2u^2} \text{d}u := 2 e^{-a^2} I_3 $$

Then

$$I_3 = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2} e^{-a^2u^2} \text{d}u = \int_0^\infty \text{d}u\, e^{-a^2u^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-x(1+u^2)} \text{d}x = \int_0^\infty \text{d}x\, e^{-x} \int_0^\infty e^{-(a^2+x)u^2} \text{d}u$$

So $$I_3 = \int_0^\infty \text{d}x e^{-x} \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^2+x}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{a^2+x}} \text{d}x$$

Let $t=\sqrt{a^2+x}$, so $x=t^2-a^2$, $\text{d}x = 2t\text{d}t$,

$$I_3 = \sqrt{\pi} \int_a^\infty e^{-(t^2-a^2)} \text{d}t = \sqrt{\pi} e^{a^2} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\, \text{erfc}(a)$$

So $$I_2 = 2e^{-a^2} I_3 =  \pi \, \text{erfc} \left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2T}}\right)$$

Same as Mhenni Benghorbal's answer, $$I_2=  \, \pi- 
{{\rm erf}\left( {\frac {b}{\sqrt {2T}}}\right)}.$$

YEAH!

Comment: Have you tried computer algebra systems?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal you mean softwares like Mathematica?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried them?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal no.. it's not free right?

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal thanks for the link, though it runs until timeout for these 2 questions, but it does help me analyzing simpler forms!

Comment: May I ask you a question. Where did these problems come from?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal it cames from http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14184/brownian-bridges-first-passage-time-distribution , actually i was trying to model human life time, so we born with Y(0) = 0 -- young, and die at time T (maybe 120 years old) Y(T) = 1 -- dead, and all along the way Y(t) can hit 1 -- any incident or disease caused ppl die... after some try i got the two integrals above.

Comment: The first one is just the derivative of the second with respect to $b^2$. So finding the second integral makes the first trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint :**
Try the substitution $$t=\cfrac{T}{u^2+1}$$

The first integral has the shape of the gaussian.
The second one leads you to $$I(\beta) = \alpha \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \cfrac{1}{u^2+1} \exp(-\beta(u^2+1)  ) \,du$$

Considering $$\begin{cases} I'(\beta)=\alpha \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \exp(-\beta(u^2+1)  ) \,du=\alpha\exp(-\beta)\cfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{\beta}} \\ I(0) = \alpha \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \cfrac{1}{u^2+1}  \,du=\cfrac{\alpha\pi}{2}\end{cases}$$

with the substitution $\gamma^2 = \beta$ ends the problem.

Comment: @Did, thanks for your comment : I've edited.

Answer (score 1):

I just briefly want to mention that these integrals are examples of convolutions and may be handled by the convolution theorem for Laplace transforms.

The convolution theorem for Laplace transforms states that, for two real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ having Laplace transforms $F$ and $G$, respectively, the following relation holds:

$$\int_0^T dt \, f(t)g(T-t) = \frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \, F(s) G(s) e^{s T} $$

where $c$ is greater than the real part of each pole of $FG$.  For example, when $f(t) = t^{-1/2} e^{-b^2/(4 t)}$ and $g(t) = t^{-1/2}$, we have $F(s) = \sqrt{\pi/s} \, e^{-b \sqrt{s}}$ and $G(s) =  \sqrt{\pi/s}$.  Accordingly, the integral is then the inverse Laplace transform of $(\pi/s) e^{-b \sqrt{s}}$, which one may show is

$$\pi \, \operatorname{erfc}{\left ( \frac{b}{2 \sqrt{T}} \right )} $$

Answer (score -1):

Here are closed forms for the first and second  integrals respectively

> $$ I_1 = {
> \frac {\sqrt {2\pi }}{b\sqrt {T}}}{{\rm e}^{-\,{\frac {{b}^{2}}{2T}}}} $$
>
> $$I_2=  \, \pi- 
> {{\rm erf}\left( {\frac {b}{\sqrt {2T}}}\right)}.$$

You can test them numerically.

Comment: -1. The question is not "what are the values of these integrals?" but "how to compute them?"

Comment: @Did: I can see that. But I wanted to tell the OP that there are closed form solutions for the integrals and he may benefit from them as these integrals came from applications.

Comment: If you just want to point out that there are closed form solutions, then why not leave a comment? As it stands, this really doesn't seem to answer the question.