# Fourier transform in PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I was trying to solve this PDE:
$\partial_t f(x,t) = -e^{-t}f(x,t)-t\partial_x f(x,t), -\infty < x < \infty, f(x,0) = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+x^2}$
I used the Fourier transform
$$f(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \hat{f}(k,t)e^{ikx} dk$$
where $\hat{f}(k,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int f(x,t)e^{-ikx}dx$
and, after some easy calculations, I obtained the following:
$$ \hat{f}(k,t) = \hat{f}(k,0)e^{-(1-e^{-t})}e^{-ikt^2/2} $$
Now I just needed to compute
$$\hat{f}(k,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int f(x,0)e^{-ikx}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-x^2-ikx}dx $$
But I've got absolutely no idea how to solve it. No complex techniques, it's not a Gaussian integral of the form $\int e^{-ay^2}e^{-iky}dy$
Is there some way of easily solving this? Or is there some kind of trick not to solve this and get straight to the expression $f(x,t)$? This is an exercise taken from an exam, so one needn't make excessively long calculations, due to the limited amount of time.
If someone could help me, I'd be much grateful

Comment: I think you might be able to adapt the calculation of $I_3$ from the body of that question to your expression, although I'm not quite sure that it's what was intended of you: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/880104/1104384

Comment: I looked up the solution. You need not solve the integral. It says that if you apply the well knows properties of the Fourier transform the calculation of $f(x)$ becomes much easier. Yet I can't what property could I apply in this scenario. I've looked them up but I don't recognize any of the situations described. I can't seem to solve this. The only thing I know is that everything I've done up to the expression of $f(k, t) $ is correct. Unfortunately the solution only tells me the procedure to follow and the final result so it's not useful right now

Comment: I would think along the lines of the shift property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there: plugging your second and third equations into the first one, we obtain
\begin{align}
f(x,t) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \hat{f}(k,0)e^{-(1-e^{-t})-\frac{i}{2}kt^2+ikx} \,dk \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{e^{-t}-1}\int e^{-\frac{i}{2}kt^2+ikx}\int f(y,0)e^{-iky}\,dy\,dk. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Changing the order of integration, we find
\begin{align}
f(x,t) &=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{e^{-t}-1}\int f(y,0)\int e^{-ik(y-x+\frac{1}{2}t^2)}\,dk\,dy \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{e^{-t}-1}\int f(y,0)\,2\pi\delta(y-x+\frac{1}{2}t^2)\,dy \\
&=e^{e^{-t}-1}f(x-\frac{1}{2}t^2,0), \tag{2}
\end{align}
which is the same result found by @Bob Terrell using the method of characteristics.

Comment: How did you get the expression with the Dirac delta. The integral  $e^{-ik(y-x+1/2t^2}$ in $dk$ does not converge. I thought about using the convolution theorem between $f(x,0)$ and $m(x) = e^{ik(x-1/2t^2-y)}$ but I don't think that was your intent. If you could tell me how to get the $2\pi \delta(...)$ then you just apply the shifting property and it's done.

Comment: Thank you lots, now it all makes perfect sense. I meant sifting property in my previous message. Pardon me for the mistake

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can get to the solution another way. The PDE is first order linear,
$$ f_t+tf_x=e^{-t}f, $$
that can be solved by characteristics. On each curve where
$dx/dt = t$, that is, on each curve $x(t) = a+\tfrac{1}{2}t^2$
you have
$$
 \frac{d}{dt}f(a+\tfrac{1}{2}t^2,t)
 =
 f_t+tf_x = -e^{-t}f.
$$
Integrate with respect to $t$ to get
$$
f(a+\tfrac{1}{2}t^2,t) = f(a,0)e^{e^{-t}-1}.
$$
Then solve $x = a+\tfrac{1}{2}t^2$ for $a$ in terms of $x$ and $t$
to get
$$
 f(x,t) = f(x-\tfrac{1}{2}t^2,0)e^{e^{-t}-1}.
$$
Now you can use your initial values.

Edit: the logic is this: we assumed a solution $f$ exists, and found a formula for it. That is a uniqueness argument. You should plug into the PDE to show that the found $f$ really is a solution.

Comment: We didn't cover characteristics, let alone mention them in our course, unfortunately, but this method really seems powerful. Thanks anyway @Bob Terrel